# Полный html-код страницы Python

Tags: python, парсер

Всем доброго времени суток.
При использовании urllib.urlopen пропадает часть html-кода и вместо этого появляется лишь 
app-root /app-root
Как с этим бороться?
Заранее спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте исходный код страницы. Возможно, что так и есть, а страница окончательно формируется на стороне клиента с помощью `JavaScript`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, это ангуляр.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Хорошо,я только начинаю пока разбираться со всем этим.Каким образом можно тогда получать оттуда информацию.Может подскажете какие-нибудь статьи по этому поводу?

Comment: Вам нужно запустить `JavaScript`, который сформирует страницу. Можете воспользоваться `Selenium`.

Comment: @XupypG Что получать инфу из страницы нужна библиотека bs4

Comment: @Vecher Я сначала использую cloudscraper ,а затем уже bs4.То есть 
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
soup = BeautifulSoup(scraper.get("url").text)

Comment: @nomnoms12, нафига запускать js, если гораздо проще послать запросы напрямую к api и просто распарсить json?